# What are some recommended online training courses (video) for Adobe illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, tutorial, video

I've just finished trialing [TutsPlus](https://tutsplus.com/) and decided not to renew as the majority of their content is coding tutorials.

However I did watch a course on Adobe illustrator which was really good and want to find other sites that have videos done by talented designs that tell you their tips and workflows for using Adobe illustrator. (i.e. not the basic Lynda type videos)

Anyone know of a decent resource? Happy to pay for them if they are high quality and by classy designers.

Answer (score 2):

[Lynda.com](http://lynda.com) always has good content.

If you are looking for something less expensive, I've had students do well by using [Virtual Training Company](http://vtc.com/) discs. They are video CDs last I looked and generally cover most of the basics for about $100.

Comment: Not fussed about the money side of it. What I don't want to basic videos on how to use the illustrator tools with very basic example projects. I want to see real world examples of art work that take you through a project so you can see the personal workflow and tips from a talented artist.

Comment: Ah then forget Video Training Company (VTC) They are geared more towards new users and cover basics. Lynda.com is probably your best bet. Or pick up some Illustrator WOW! books.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say that Deke McLelland's Illustrator One-on-One Advanced and Mastery courses on [Lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/Illustrator-training-tutorials/227-0.html) are probably the best resource. They go far beyond the basics (as do most Lynda course series).

Mordy Golding is something close to an international strategic asset for Illustrator training. He also has excellent AI titles on Lynda and many great videos on his [blog](http://rwillustrator.blogspot.com/) and on [Adobe TV](http://tv.adobe.com/search/?q=Mordy%20Golding&product_id=4&topic_id=&release_id=&t_lid=).

Both [Nigel French](http://www.lynda.com/search?q=nigel%20french&x=0&y=0) and [Bert Monroy](http://www.lynda.com/search?q=bert%20monroy&x=0&y=0) get into specific applications and techniques in their respective AI titles on Lynda, and I'd highly recommend both.

Answer (score 0):

[Train Simple](http://www.trainsimple.com/) is great and about $10 monthly with unlimited access to Adobe Illustrator training videos not to mention they're endorsed as a registered training center by Adobe. They seem pretty good from what I've watched.

Answer (score 0):

ThinkB!G Learn Smart has online live training courses that are taught by Adobe Certified Instructors. They are only two days and you can ask the live instructor questions - so you really get a lot of bang for your buck. They even send you an official book and certificate of completion. You can check out their [Adobe Illustrator training](http://thinkbiglearnsmart.com/illustrator-creative-cloud-training-course/) here.

Answer (score 0):

[Digital Tutors](http://www.digitaltutors.com/software/Illustrator-tutorials) is another great resource. They are a subscription based service, but their videos are very high quality and easy to follow.